# Flutterflow saves string/number in different variable in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, flutterflow

This is a really weird scenario like ive never seen.

So i have a counter which is assigned to a specific variable in the DB called q1
I have another datepicker assigned to reqDate variable in the DB

but for some reason, q1 which is supposed to have a counter aka number shows the date picked
while the reqDate variable shows nothing.

please see imgs below & advise?

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCxt0.png)

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pau8u.png)

thanks in advance for the help!

tried changing multiple times and redoing the entire function but no use